# Content shows scrollbar but is not scrollable

Tags: html, css

I wan't the content to scroll up but it should never be visible behind the menu.
Which is hard cause it's transparant. So I use a div to use it as a mask.
But for some reason that doesn't allow for my content to scroll.

HTML:

```
<div class="title">
    title
</div>
<div class="menu">
    menu
    <button class="btn">Foo</button>
</div>
<div class="content-mask">
  <div class="asfsadf">
    scroll content<br/>
    scroll content<br/>
    scroll content<br/>
    scroll content<br/>
    scroll content<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
   position: fixed; 
   top: 0;
}
.menu {
   position: fixed; 
   top: 20px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
.content-mask {
   position: fixed; 
   top: 40px;
   overflow: scroll;
}
.content {
}
body {
   background-image:  url("https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ChtN47lVAAAQWD1.jpg:large");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/34Lf1mke/

Answer (score 0):

Add height to .content-mask:

```
.content-mask {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 40px;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ha45uao/

Or just add height and overflow: auto to content container:

```
.asfsadf {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/34Lf1mke/3/

If you care about old browsers, you can make javascript fallback to calculate height.

Answer (score 0):

You should used background color for your fixed div with 100% width.
And set top-margin to "content-mask" div as height of fixed div.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.asfsadf{
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the scrolling the container using [overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp), the container must be given a fixed height and width.

> **Live Demo:**
>  https://jsfiddle.net/0t8oh85y/

---

The corrected css in your case is.

```
.title {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.content-mask {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: calc( 100% - 40px);
  width: calc( 100% );
}
.content {
}
html{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ChtN47lVAAAQWD1.jpg:large");
  background-size:cover; 
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---